# Prevent loading data until event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I have a bunch of GridView on one page, and each have their own coordinating SqlDataSource.

They all load their coordinating data when initializing the page (on the page load). I want to Load the data for specific SqlDataSource(s) on the page when the user clicks a button, so that it is not trying to load ALL the data for all the different grids all at the same time when the page initially loads.

Note: I need to also have Paging working, and anything I have tried so far has broken the paging functionality.

Looking to tell the SqlDataSource what data to bind to it after the user clicks a button, and then have the specific GridView Bind that data to it and have the Paging functionality work with the data it was told to load.

Environment: C#, WebForms, ASP.NET, .NET 3.5, Controls SqlDataSource / GridView

From what I can tell it correctly binds the data, but the 'gridview' control keeps disappearing when I click one of the pages at the bottom for the paging.

Note: If I click the button again, it will show the correct page and the correct data for the page.

```
protected void btn_LoadData2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { Gridview2.DataSourceID = "DataSource2"; Gridview2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DataNeeded"; Gridview2.DataBind(); Gridview2.DataBind(); }
```

Comment: Please show your code, it seems you are linking your GridViews to a SqlDataSource at your HTML, it's better to do so at your code behind, thus you can specifically load the GridView whenever you want (e.g. Load, Click events)

Comment: From what I can tell it looks to be correctly binding the data, but the 'gridview' control keeps disappering when I click one of the pages at the bottom for the paging for some reason.  Note:  If I click the button again, it will show the correct page and the correct data for the page.  Not sure why.

<code>
 protected void btn_LoadData2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gridview2.DataSourceID = "DataSource2";
        Gridview2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DataNeeded";
        Gridview2.DataBind();
        Gridview2.DataBind();
    }
<code>

Answer (score 1):

Add a Selecting event to each of your data sources.  Then in the code behind check if IsPostBack and if IsPostBack is false then cancel the operation.

```
protected void MyDataSource_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```